# Best practice for asynch loads that may be same address

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, caching, asynchronous, uiimage

I download images from Amazon's Web Services for a UITableView. I also use a singleton to cache recent images. I am wondering how to best handle a situation where, for example, I have two cells in view and both are actually using the same key (URL would be the same scenario if using NSURLSession). There's obviously no need to download the image twice, but checking the cache will not return a result as the first download will not be complete when the second one begins. My current logic is to use an additional NSDictionary singleton which will contain a key for each image that is currently downloading, but not complete. I will check against that after checking the cache, and if the key exists, I will add a reference of the UIImageView to the key's array - when this download is complete, this array can then be utilized to update all the UIImageViews referenced in the array. This isn't exactly a "clean" way to do it in my opinion - is there a better practice for handling this? While this question is more conception, here's my current code:

custom_image_view.m

```
-(void)set_image:(NSString *)key desired_size:(CGSize)desired_size
{
singleton *caches = [singleton instance];
if (!key.length || [key isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    return;
}
if (![caches is_file_cached:key type:IMAGE_CACHE])
{
//should i check a new dictionary here to see if it's currently downloading?
//if downloading, add self to array and return
//if not downloading, make new key
    NSString *bucket = @"bucket.mysite.com";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents_directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *image_path =[documents_directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",@"cached"]];

//only relevant for AWS users
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:@"accesskey" secretKey:@"secretkey"];
    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    download_request = [AWSS3GetObjectRequest new];
    download_request.bucket = bucket;
    download_request.key = key;
    download_request.downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:image_path];
    AWSS3 *transferManager = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSLog(@"manager: %@",transferManager);
//begin request
    [[transferManager getObject:download_request] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
     {
         if (task.error != nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"error");
             if(task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled && task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused)
             {
                 NSLog(@"error code: %@",task.error);
                 NSLog(@"key: %@",key);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             //successful download
             self->download_request = nil;
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                            {
                                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:image_path];
                                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                if (image != nil)
                                {
                                    self.image = [self crop_image:image to_size:desired_size];
     //loop through new dictionary's array and assign image to each as well?
                                    [caches add_file_to_cache:key withData:data type:IMAGE_CACHE];
                                }
                            });
         }
         return nil;
     }];
}
else
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                   {
                       NSData *data = [caches get_cached_data:key type:IMAGE_CACHE];
                       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                       self.image = [self crop_image:image to_size:desired_size];
                   });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoltsFramework has made this task a bit easier for you, but you will still need SOME SORT of cache.

`getObject:` returns a `BFTask`. `continueWithBlock:` is a handy method on `BFTask` that will execute a block after the task has completed. It is also already able to attribute multiple blocks to be executed with the same task's completion, saving you a lot of work. All that's left to pull the whole thing together is just a simple cache from image_path to `BFTask`s. Here's some code to better explain.

Somewhere:

```
static NSMutableDictionary * _imagePathToTask = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Instead of:

```
[[transferManager getObject:download_request] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
```

Do something like this:

```
BFTask *task = [_imagePathToTask objectForKey:image_path];
if (task == nil) {
    task = [transferManager getObject:download_request];
    [_imagePathToTask setObject:task forKey:image_path];
}
[task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
```

Even if the task is completed, your block will be called with the task. So for as long as your dictionary is around, your image requests can all be sent off knowing you won't download the same image twice.

Now the only last thing that is sketchy is how we're storing the dictionary. A better approach might be to create a category for `AWSS3` that returns you a BFTask for a file path. Doing so would make your implementation above back to the same amount of code in the `UIImageView` category. You could use an [associated object](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to store the image_path->task dictionary on the AWSS3 instance. I reckon you might wrap one of those up for reuse anyhow, but perhaps you omitted that from your code to keep your example brief.

Edit:
But I suppose to more directly answer your question, you have the right idea. If you look at [BFTask](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/blob/master/Bolts/Common/BFTask.m) and the callbacks `NSMutableArray`, they are doing just about what you described. The big difference is the level in the application in which they are doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Acey! Got me where I needed to be. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use SDWebImage available on GitHub visit  https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.
Go through it,i have used it in my project under same scenario its helpful. 
This library provides a category for UIImageView with support for remote images coming from the web.
It is basically asynchronous image downloader with cache support with a UIImageView category.